# Issue while launching jenkins

Tags: macos, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have installed jenkins on Mac OS El Capitan from jenkins package.

Installation was successfully and it automatically launched the browser but then i got the error that "Cycle Detected" on browser (http://localhost:8080).

Then i tried with http://:8080 then i got "Connection Refused"

Below are the screenshot of both scenario's

[image]

[image]

Comment: The issue is with the firewall of the network. When i tried in an Open Internet it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue. I restart the machine and sometimes this works.

Comment: Issue seems to be with firewall of the network. Try the installation on your home PC or Open Wifi network. It will work.